# Object Creation in Shared Memory using Boost.Interprocess

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

Im trying to learn how to create an object in a shared memory such that multiple processes can write/read to/from a shared queue. When a process writes into the queue it can signal other processes using the boost condition variable. I am not so familiar with shared memory applications, so please correct my code.

My object would be as shown below,

```
typedef boost::interprocess::vector < uint8_t > buffer_t;

struct QueueType
{
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition Signal;
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex Mutex;
    boost::interprocess::deque < buffer_t > Queue;
};
```

My code for allocating an object of the above class is as below,

```
managed_shared_memory _shm_mem;
std::string _shm_name;
QueueType * _queue;

bool Start()
{
    bool result ( false );
    try 
    {
        _shm_mem = managed_shared_memory ( open_or_create, _shm_name.c_str(), 65536);   
        _queue = _shm_mem.find_or_construct<QueueType>("Queue")();
        if ( _queue != NULL ) 
        {
           result = true;
        }   
    }
    catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception &e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using the above code Im unable to get a valid _queue object.

Comment: I fixed the issue by calling  shared_memory_object::remove(_shm_name.c_str()); before opening the same shared memory